# how to make it trigger/alert every 5 minutes in angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

```
  limitExceed(params: any) {
    params.forEach((data: any) => {
      if (data.humidity === 100) {
        this.createNotification('warning', data.sensor, false);
      } else if (data.humidity >= 67 && data.humidity <= 99.99) {
        this.createNotification('warning', data.sensor, true);
      }
    });
  }

  createNotification(type: string, title: string, types: boolean): void {
    this.notification.config({
      nzPlacement: 'bottomRight',
      nzDuration: 5000,
    });
    if (types) {
      this.notification.create(
        type,
        title,
        'Humidity reached the minimum limit'
      );
    } else {
      this.notification.create(
        type,
        title,
        'Humidity reached the maximum'
      );
    }
  }
```

how to make it trigger/alert every 5 minutes.
but first it will alert then after the first alert/trigger it will alert/trigger again every 5 minutes.

cause I already set the `setInterval` like this.

```
setInterval(() => {
if (types) {
      this.notification.create(
        type,
        title,
        'Humidity reached the minimum limit'
      );
    } else {
      this.notification.create(
        type,
        title,
        'Humidity reached the maximum'
      );
    }
    }, 300000);
```

but it didn't alert/trigger first.

Comment: You could either call it directly on the first notification while setting the interval or make it an recursive function with a setTimeout of 5min.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could create your notifications first, once, then set the interval:

```
function createNotification() {
  this.notification.create(...);
}

createNotification();

setInterval(() => {
  createNotification();
}, 300000);
```

Or, even cleaner, you could use the `timer()` `Observable`:

```
import {timer} from 'rxjs';

// starts immediately, then every 5 minutes
timer(0, 300000).subscribe(() => { 
  this.notification.create(...);
});
```

Comment: Oh very nice, I had never heard of RxJS's `timer`

Comment: RxJS has SO MANY methods, once you get used to it it's crazy what you can do with them, like listening to document scroll events, debounce them, call an API every 1 seconds of scrolling... It's so good :s

Answer (score 2):

You could use an immediately invoking function inside setInterval:

```
setInterval(function notification() {
    if (types) {
      this.notification.create(
        type,
        title,
        'Humidity reached the minimum limit'
      );
    } else {
      this.notification.create(
        type,
        title,
        'Humidity reached the maximum'
      );
    }
    return notification;
    }(), 300000);
```

Just by returning the function and placing that `()` it would get immediately executed once after its declaration and then in the actual setInterval().

A simple example to test:

```js
setInterval(function notification() {
  console.log('notification');
  return notification;
}(), 3000);
```

Answer (score 2):

1. Put your code in a method.
2. Call this method.
3. Additionally, call this method every 5 minutes with an interval.

```
    createNotification() {
      if (types) {
        ...
      } else {
        ...
      }
    }

    // then in another method : 

    this.createNotification();

    setInterval(() => {
      this.createNotification();
    }, 300000);

    // Or more simply : 

    this.createNotification();

    setInterval(() => this.createNotification.bind(this) , 300000);
```